# URL Rewrite to subdomains?

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

say i have a website with `/article.php?id=1&category=Minecraft&Name=Lorem+Ipsum`

and `/topic.php?category=Minecraft`

how would i setup url rewrite to make the topic pages being

```
minecraft.domain.com
```

and articles being

```
minecraft.domain.com/1/Lorem+Ipsum
```

I couldn't find this how to do this anywhere on the web... well, at least on google

Comment: Cannot change the case of categories (without inserting each one manually) and cannot deal with spaces easily. Look at it in reverse, given a URL how does the web server know what the underlying page should be? Changing domain/subdomain without redirects can also unravel site security.

Answer (score 2):

1) On your website, make sure that you generate **PROPER** URLs, e.g. `http://minecraft.domain.com/1/lorem-ipsum` instead of `/article.php?id=1&category=Minecraft&Name=Lorem+Ipsum`

Here, the acceptable characters for the article name is:

- any latin characters (can be mixed case, but I would recommend to have all lower case)
- digits
- underscore char `_`
- minus char `-`

Any other characters should be replaced by `-`. If during URL normalisation you end up with more that 1 `-` character next to each other -- remove such extra chars. The article name should not start or end with `-` or `_`.

Example of normalisation process (step-by-step):

- `Oops! I did it again!` -- initial text
- `oops--i-did-it-again-` -- after replacing unwanted characters by `-`
- `oops-i-did-it-again-` -- removing duplicated `-` characters
- `oops-i-did-it-again` -- final sting after removing trailing `-`

2) Setup your subdomain `minecraft.domain.com` to point into the same root folder as `domain.com`

3) Add these rules into your .htaccess

```
# Activate Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
# Do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
# rewrite root (topic) hit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minecraft\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /topic.php?category=Minecraft [QSA,L]
# rewrite article hits
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minecraft\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)$ /article.php?id=$1&category=Minecraft&Name=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

These rules will do these rewrites:

`minecraft.domain.com` => `/topic.php?category=Minecraft`

`minecraft.domain.com/1/lorem-ipsum` => `/article.php?id=1&category=Minecraft&Name=lorem-ipsum`

---

**UPDATE:**

These rules will work for any subdomains (including www.domain.com) -- replace last 6 lines from previous snippet:

```
# rewrite root (topic) hit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /topic.php?category=%1 [QSA,L]
# rewrite article hits
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)$ /article.php?id=$1&category=%1&Name=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

It is YOUR responsibility to generate PROPER URLs. The above rules will make these NICE urls working.

Comment: no, i mean like the subdomain is used based on the category so i could create an article with a new cateogyr and it would go to a new subdomain. Ex: /topic.php?category=Minecraft -> minecraft.domain.com and when i create a new category ex: /topic.php?category=Ipsum
 it would go to Ipsum.domain.com // I head of something called a wildcard subdomain but not sure how to set it up

Comment: @David I have updated my answer. Configuring Apache to accept any sub-domain name (`*.domain.com`) is out of the scope of this answer and the whole site as well. If you need this -- then better ask it at sister site -- [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/). I apologies if I STILL did not understood you correctly. If that is the case -- please elaborate.